# How to make screen reader not to read out the span tag inside the paragraph tag?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

Consider the following element:
`<p>Hello <span class='nowrap'>Samuel L. Chang</span></p>`
The .nowrap class has css styles whitespace nowrap
When using screen reader, the screen reader will read out the span tag, character by character
Based on what I have found, there's no `role='text'` 
How do I make screen readers ignore the node and read it as plain text?

Thx!

Comment: Could you please 1. provide a link to an example page, and 2. tell exactly with which screen reader, browser and OS you noticed the problem ? If you don't add these infos, the question is going to be closed because of a lack of precisions. Thank you.

Comment: I don’t think my problem is so complicated that it needs a website example to demonstrate it. I think the simple example I mentioned already covers what the problem exactly is.

Comment: That's a question of convenience for those who are going to help you. Don't make them waste more time than necessary. Just a simple page with the minimal code is sufficient; a jsfeedle or anything alike will do.

Comment: While an example may not be needed (but would be welcomed to save ahving to set one up ourselves) could you please let us know what screen reader and OS as @QuentinC asked, it will help us identify the issue as with NVDA this works as expected. Also how are you reading the page (are you just leaving it to read or are you navigating by element) as I can't replicate the problem, it could just be how you are navigating but I am unsure. p.s. `role="text"` is a non-standard role that works on some mobiles . While definitely a hack and not official, it may solve this issue on VoiceOver for example.